# Is it possible to do some kind of loop in a WHERE clause to run multiple PATINDEX searches dynamically?

Tags: sql-server

This is not for a production system, but for for an internal tool I work with.. performance doesn't matter much.

Essentially what I'm doing is storing a set of rules in a table that is used to filter out results from another query.  Most of the rules are simple column matches, in which case I can do something like

```
WHERE somecolumn NOT IN (SELECT rule FROM Rules)
```

But one of the other rules I need to check is a text search, so I would store values like `%some%text%`.. so I need to accomplish something like:

```
WHERE
    <for each rule in Rules>
    PATINDEX(rule,sometextcolumn) = 0
    </for each>
```

There is no sort of `IN` statement equivalent that I can use to process multiple text searches dynamically.

Any tips?

Comment: Use dynamic SQL and build up the WHERE

Answer (score 2):

We don't use loops in SQL (if we can avoid it). We use *sets*, and try to write set-based code.

So, we'd have something like:

```
WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT * from Rules r
    WHERE PATINDEX(r.rule,sometextcolumn) = 0)
```

(Substituting `EXISTS` and `NOT EXISTS` and `= 0` for other comparisons to achieve whatever `AND` or `OR` combination between multiple rules we were actually trying to enforce)

Comment: Great answer, thanks! I will try this.  I know loops are a no-no, I just didn't know how else to explain it :)